# Excel (via web) SheetName as cell value

Tags: excel, office365

I have a formula that grabs the name of the sheet and stores it in the cell.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A2),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A2))+1,255)
```

I use this as a header for different columns and charts throughout the workbook. I "shared" my workbook to OneDrive, which allows other users to access the workbook via web. The formula breaks when viewing via web. I have a feeling it is due to the self-referencing "filename" parameter. Anyone know a good workaround?

Comment: Shouldn't just `CELL("filename")` be enough? (no need for a ref as log as it stays in the same WB)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't look like CELL() is a recognized function within the online workspace. Bummer.